# how to add text color to button in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, button

hi i want to add color to the text inside button and also want to remove border and outline from the button but i couldnt fix it.please anybody help me out.i am using jquery-mobile.

```
<div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-corner="false">

           <input type="submit" value="post" id="post" onClick="postprivate()"  style="color:green;" ></input>
            </div>
```

and this is the css which i am trying but its not applied at all

```
#post{color:green;
 text-decoration:none:
 font-size:24px;
 margin-right:20px;
 outline:none;
 width:60px;
 border:0px;
 display:block;}
```

Comment: With what I understand from your requirement, i think your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/yfpmhnnw/ (Check this fiddle, i have not changed anything, is the output what your are trying to achieve ?)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile provides an attribute called **[data-wrapper-class](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#option-wrapperClass)** that applys a named CSS class to the ui-btn DIV it creates when enhancing the input. So you can do something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="post" id="post" onClick="postprivate()" data-wrapper-class="mybuttonstyle"></input>

.mybuttonstyle {
    color: green !important;
    font-size:24px !important;
    margin-right:20px;
    outline:none;
    width:60px;
    border:0px;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9h0tpu35/)**

Comment: yes i have seen but in my app its not working..i also dont know why its not working..

Comment: @user3248668, you need to tell us which versions of jQM and jQuery you are using and show more code for your page setup. Even better, try to reproduce the problem in jsFiddle for us...

Comment: @ezanker..thanks for telling.after changing jquery mobile version now its working....

Comment: Thank you @ezanker ! I was looking for this for ages and could not solve it. Works now!!

Comment: @merlin, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

if you inspect element, you will find out `input` does not display, a `span class="ui-btn-inner"` instead it.

[image]

so using js code to change the span color property

```
$(function()
{
$('#post').prev('span.ui-btn-inner').css('color','green');
});
```

**the result**

[image]

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/6rbf2Lmu/

Comment: @Cattla..still not working.....same problem.is there any another solution for this